# How to create a signer object from an address in ethers?

Tags: testing, ethers.js, hardhat

I have a list of addresses, and I would like to use them to test my contract in my hardhat ethers project. Normally I get a list of addresses like this:

`[a, b, c] = await ethers.getSigners()`

but what I want to do is take address `0x70997970C51812dc3A010C7d01b50e0d17dc79C8` and make it into a signer object so I can call:

`contract.connect("0x70997970C51812dc3A010C7d01b50e0d17dc79C8").method()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since a signer can be a Wallet, VoidSigner or JsonRpcSigner, you can use the `jsonRpcProvider.getSigner( [ addressOrIndex ] )` which returns a `JsonRpcSigner`.

Comment: Can you show how you instantiated `jsonRpcProvider` ?

Comment: @James here is the documentation https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/providers/jsonrpc-provider/

Answer (score 2):

The simplest answer is to use the deployed contract which already has a provider..

```
contract.provider.getSigner('0x70997970C51812dc3A010C7d01b50e0d17dc79C8')
```

Comment: In your above answer.Is the address account address or the contract address or something else ?? `contract.provider.getSigner('0x70997970C51812dc3A010C7d01b50e0d17dc79C8')`